# Flutter Geocoding address

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I want to get coordinates and full/real address depending on what I write on a `TextField`.

From the [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding) Flutter package, i can see the following example :

```
List<Location> locations = await locationFromAddress("Gronausestraat 710, Enschede");
```

So i have tried to write "Paris" and call `locationFromAddress("Paris")`.
But it doesn't find any result because the address is malformed.

When i was developping my Android app with Google maps, i could even write "Lond" and it was finding "London" (I am **not** speaking about the PlaceAutoComplete API).

When you search a location you don't want to have to write the full address...

So how can i achieve this simple use case in Flutter ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use try this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder)

Sample code:

```dart
    import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';

    final query = "1600 Amphiteatre Parkway, Mountain View";
    var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(query);
    var first = addresses.first;
    print("${first.featureName} : ${first.coordinates}");
    
    // From coordinates
    final coordinates = new Coordinates(1.10, 45.50);
    addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
    first = addresses.first;
    print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
```

Comment: It's the old package, Geocoding is maintained by baseflow.com and has the same functionnalities that i am interrested in. 
Unfortunately this doesn't answer my needs as the issue is the same with Geocoder anyway, i doubt that if you write "Paris" in your ```query``` this will output "Paris, France" etc...

Comment: Hi, @Tom3652, did you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi @bluepine, no unfortunately i would have posted it here :/ 
I have removed this feature from my app for now...